# Maximum Weight Independent Set in Circular-Arc Graphs (Proof of A Lemma)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, correctness-proof

I am reading the paper: "Maximum Weight Independent Set Of Circular-Arc Graphs and It's Applications" (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02832044). And I had a question regarding the proof of Lemma 3 in the paper. It is stated as follows.

If $X$ is the maximum weight independent set of the circular-arc graph $A$, then for any clique $Z$ of $A$, we have that $\| X \cap Z\| = 1$.

The paper then proves this by contradiction in two cases, the first when $\| X \cap Z\| \geq 2$ and the second when $\| X \cap Z\| = 0$. I buy the argument for the first case, but I am concerned about the argument they make for the case equal to 0. Their argument goes as follows: If $\| X \cap Z\| = 0$, then including any vertex in $Z$ into $X$ will remain independent and the weight will be greater than the previous set, contradicting the fact that $X$ was a maximum weight independent set. To me, this statement does not seem true.

[image: Circular Graph Example]

If we pick vertices 8, 6, and 3 to have weight 1000, and all other vertices to have weight 1, then clearly {8, 6, 3} is a maximum weight independent set. However, their exists cliques of size two (edges) that have an empty intersection with {8, 6, 3}... such as the edge {1, 2}. You can also extend this to cliques of size 3 by adding an arc that intersects with arcs {8, 2, 1} then the clique formed by this new arc and arcs 1 and 2 will have an empty intersection as well.

So where have I gone wrong in my understanding? I feel like I must be missing something really obvious. Clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The lemma is wrong.

Comment: Thought so - Should the lemma be $\leq 1$ instead of $= 1$? Also, They are using lemma 3 to prove lemma 4 and so forth, but luckily, I believe that lemma 4 can be proven in a different way without lemma 3.

Comment: The lemma is true with $\leq 1$, but this trivial mistakes makes me doubt the entire paper. If you are going to use the result, make sure that you understand the entire proof. Once you have done that, you could answer the questions with the necessary corrections.

Comment: You are right. The paper has several key flaws in it, but I've noticed that the main algorithm only uses lemma's 5 through 7 (which seem correct). Although there are some errors in lemmas 1, 3 and 4... they are not vital to the core result (for whatever reason). I've mailed the findings to my prof and awaiting her response, as this was going to be a paper used in a project for that course. Even for the lemmas that seem correct, the proofs are badly written, making me doubt the entire result as well.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Make these observations into a short answer? If not, just ping me and I'll make it CW. Thanks!

Comment: @Juho Please go ahead and answer it yourself. I think a proper answer should explain whether the main results are correct or not.